# How to Set JSON PropertyNamingPolicy when using Results.OK in Minimal API when JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy has no effect?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, system.text.json, jsonserializer, minimal-apis

I am using a Minimal API to recreate an old REST service and so I need to mimic the functionality of the previous service as close as possible. Information in the old service is returned Pascal case and I know that there are some old clients that are case-sensitive. Out of the box .NET 6 serializes to camel case on the web but that can be overridden with code such as:

```
builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
});
```

If a breakpoint is set I can see that the policy is originally set to camel case and then reset to null. If I then use `JsonSerializer.Serialize` it works as expected. The only issue is if I use `Results.OK(colection)` it is back to camel case as if it is ignoring the options settings. I can set all the property names with declarative attributes on the model class and that works as expected so inline declarations work but setting on the service level does not. So, what options is the 'Results.OK' response pipeline looking at?

EDIT: Corrected method name

Comment: What casing are you expecting to return here? Give an example.

Comment: Also, did you mean that you are returning `Results.OK` rather than `Return.OK`?

Comment: Pascal casing is first letter of each compound word capitalized while camel case is first letter lowercase and then the first letter of each compound word capitalized. In truth I would like to have the formatting just left alone which was the former default.

Comment: Yes, 'Results' not 'Return'. I will correct the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are actually two different `JsonOptions` in Asp.Net core:

1. [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json.JsonOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.json.jsonoptions?view=aspnetcore-6.0)
2. [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.jsonoptions?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

I think you're using the Mvc version - switching to the first one above should fix the issue and return the correct Json casing.  The [`Results`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.results?source=recommendations&view=aspnetcore-6.0) class is a member of the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` namespace which could explain why it uses different `JsonOptions` from Mvc.

You could create an alias at the top of the file (or just reference the full namespace):

```
using JsonOptions = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json.JsonOptions;
...
builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
});
```

Note that the options property name is different (`JsonSerializerOptions` vs `SerializerOptions`) but all the options should be the same.

Comment: **Note**: By my experience, even if you are using the minimal version (`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json.JsonOptions`) you still have to configure the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonOptions` as well, otherwise swagger won't parse the request body using your desired naming policies.

Answer (score 0):

I was in need to change it alternative to the default one, so in the end I did it like this:

First create a `CustomJsonResult` class

```cs
using System.Net;
using System.Text.Json;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace XYZ;

public class CustomJsonResult : IResult
{
    private readonly object? _value;
    private readonly JsonSerializerOptions? _jsonSerializerOptions;

    public CustomJsonResult(object? value, JsonSerializerOptions? jsonSerializerOptions)
    {
        _value = value;
        _jsonSerializerOptions = jsonSerializerOptions;
    }

    public async Task ExecuteAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        HttpResponse response = httpContext.Response;
        response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
        response.ContentType = "application/json";

        string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(_value, _jsonSerializerOptions);
        await response.WriteAsync(json);
    }
    
    public static IResult Ok(object? value, JsonSerializerOptions? jsonSerializerOptions)
    {
        return new CustomJsonResult(value, jsonSerializerOptions);
    }
    
    public static IResult Ok<TResult>(TResult? value, JsonSerializerOptions? jsonSerializerOptions)
    {
        return new CustomJsonResult(value, jsonSerializerOptions);
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```cs
internal static async Task<IResult>? Handler(....)
    {
        ...
    
        MyResponse result = new()
        {
            ...
        };
        
        return CustomJsonResult.Ok(result, new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase
        });
    }
```