# System.Text.Json: How can I enforce default camelCase JsonNamingPolicy when Serializing data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, .net, system.text.json

I have this annoying problem where the moment I add a custom JSON converter the naming policy is not respected when Deserializing properties. It defaults to PascalCase always no matter what.

I can also replicate this with a minimal Web API using .NET 6.

**Programs.cs**

```cs
using System.Text.Json;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json;
using MinimalWebApi.Converters;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddMvc();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>(
    options => {
        options.SerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new FooModelJsonConverter());
        //NOTE: This is the default policy but enabling it does not make a difference.
        //options.SerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
    }
);

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

**FooModelJsonConverter.cs**

```cs
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using MinimalWebApi.Model;

namespace MinimalWebApi.Converters;

public class FooModelJsonConverter: JsonConverter<FooModel>
{
    public override FooModel Read(
        ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
        Type typeToConvert,
        JsonSerializerOptions options
    )
    {

        return
            JsonSerializer.Deserialize<FooModel>(ref reader, options)
            ?? throw new JsonException("FooModel could not be deserialized as it was null!");

    }

    public override void Write(
        Utf8JsonWriter writer,
        FooModel fooModel,
        JsonSerializerOptions options
    ) {

        writer.WriteStartObject();

        var majorVersion = fooModel.MajorVersion;
        var minorVersion = fooModel.MinorVersion;

        if (majorVersion == null || minorVersion == null)
            throw new JsonException(
                $"Expected a 'Major' & 'Minor' attribute but one (or both) of them is null => MajorVersion: {majorVersion}\nMinorVersion: {minorVersion}!"
            );

        switch (majorVersion)
        {
            case 1:
                writer.WritePropertyName(TryParseCamelCase(nameof(fooModel.Id), options, true));
                JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, fooModel.Id, options);
                switch (minorVersion)
                {
                    case 0:
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        writer.WritePropertyName(TryParseCamelCase(nameof(fooModel.AnotherId), options, true));
                        JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, fooModel.AnotherId, options);
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new JsonException($"Unexpected 'Minor' version attribute: {minorVersion}");
                }
                writer.WritePropertyName(TryParseCamelCase(nameof(fooModel.Name), options, true));
                JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, fooModel.Name, options);
                writer.WritePropertyName(TryParseCamelCase(nameof(fooModel.Status), options, true));
                JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, fooModel.Status, options);
                break;
            default:
                throw new JsonException($"Unexpected 'Major' version attribute: {majorVersion}");
        }

        writer.WriteEndObject();

    }

    public static string TryParseCamelCase(string propertyName, JsonSerializerOptions options, bool disabled = false)
    {

        var namingPolicy = options.PropertyNamingPolicy;

        if (!disabled)
            return namingPolicy != null ? namingPolicy.ConvertName(propertyName) : propertyName;
        else
            return propertyName;

    }

}
```

**FooModel.cs**

```cs
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using MinimalWebApi.Converters;

namespace MinimalWebApi.Model
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(FooModelJsonConverter))]
    public class FooModel
    {

        public enum State { STARTED, RUNNING, COMPLETED, FAILED };

        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        
        public string? AnotherId { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }

        [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
        public State Status { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public int? MajorVersion { get; set; } = 1;
        
        [JsonIgnore]
        public int? MinorVersion { get; set; } = 0;

    }


}
```

As you can see I have found a workaround by explicitly invoking the `ConvertName` method from the `PropertyNamingPolicy`. However, I wonder how can I force my Controller to properly serialize this?
Be aware, I have tried to explicitly specify the CamelCase option when adding services (see code above; **Program.cs**), create a new instance of `JsonSerializerOptions` inside my custom `FooModelJsonConverter` and also specifying an explicit `ActionResult` in my controller but these didn't work. Any ideas on this one anyone?

**P.S.**: This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73787887/how-to-set-json-propertynamingpolicy-when-using-results-ok-in-minimal-api-when-j) claims we should be using `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;` instead of `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json;` and further in the responses / comments below people suggest configuring those as Swashbuckle will not be able to parse the JSON response body correctly. However, I have my doubts if this is correct and / or makes sense.

Comment: Instead of setting CamelCase option in your Converter class, have you tried creating new `JsonSerializerOptions` where you make the http call? 
I assume you want to do something like this? 
`JsonSerializer.Serialize(payload, options)`

Comment: I have tried doing it this within the converter and outside of it but there is no point doing that latter part as then we negate all the positive effects of using the middleware in the first place polluting the code with various (de)serializations explicit calls which we do not want. Plus, everything else works within the converter or if we change any other JSON option when doing the DI so I see no reason why this is not respected as a setting.

Comment: You wrote, *I have this annoying problem where the moment I add a custom JSON converter the naming policy is not respected when Deserializing properties.* -- but if try to run your code, `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<FooModel>(jsonString, options);` will throw a StackOverflowException, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/XGrlwf.  The problem is that you applied `[JsonConverter(typeof(FooModelJsonConverter))]` directly to the model, which means your recursive call to deserialize will invoke the converter recursively.  Can you show you share some actual deserialization code which is causing problems?

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question.
You saying ` the naming policy is not respected when Deserializing properties. ` but you are referring to the code related to the serializaton.
In your Write method you are using `nameof(fooModel.Id)` to get the field name and it returns Pascal Case as expected. 
You are passing this string to the `TryParseCamelCase` with `disabled == true` which causes to return it as is.
are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @dbc I don't think dotnetfiddle can understand middleware. If you run this in a VS project it works perfectly fine :) Also, the annotation should be applied directly to the model per ... MS documentation: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0#registration-sample---jsonconverter-on-a-type for more info. I followed this example and it works like a charm in my case :)

Comment: @Vyacheslav Benedichuk The disabled that there is temporarily and acts as a switch to confirm behaviour. If you remove the statements that set this flag to false it will still not respect the default JSON Naming policy aka Camel Case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [GH-31818 issue: WritePropertyName in JsonConverter doesn't respect casing](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31818) this is intended behaviour so I have to invoke explicitly the ConvertName from the respective JsonNamingPolicy.